# Website css not getting load initally during loading. Divi Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, divi

I am having a very odd issue with my Wordpress Divi website. The website when loads it is complete distorted (No Css applied) initially. During loading process the website comes back in shape.

I have tried to search multiple forums in which they say the divi works like that and apply the css when the content is loaded. They also suggested to have a pre-loader but that is not what my client wants.

How can i resolve it? I am not getting much help from the forums.

The link to website is

https://www.fixngotx.net/

Kindly help me on it

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think a preloader can solve your problem, the client can't see your page until it's completely loading. try using this plugin : https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/the-preloader/

Comment: i did mention that pre-loader indeed solved the problem but my client don't want the pre-loader

Comment: @kool_Coder The issue appears to be on Cloudflare’s end.

Your HTML loads quick since that’s coming from your site’s cache, but the resources being loaded through Cloudflare’s CDN (your CSS and JavaScript files) are taking longer to load. you can contact cloudflare’s support about this

Comment: i just checked via gt-metrix the cloudflear cdn is not being used